# How can I connect one IBOutlet to an tableview controller in an container view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

[image]

I have designed my app with Storyboard, I have one View controller and I need to insert a static table view controller (static table view controller can't insert into a view controller ). So I've drag&drop a container view controller and embed with a table view controller.

Now I have a IBOutlet declared in my viewcontroller.h, as

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UITableView *infoTableView;
```

How can I connect the infoTableView to the actual table view in connections inspector?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean connect an IBOutlet that's in ItemEditorViewController to the table view in the table view controller, you can't. It's not possible to connect an outlet in one controller to an object in another controller. If you need to get a reference to that table view in the parent controller, you need to do it code:

In ItemEditorViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UITableView *infoTableView;
```

In ItemEditorViewController.m (probably in viewDidLoad)

```
self.infoTableView = [self.childViewControllers[0] tableView];
```

Answer (score -1):

It is not quite the answer you are looking for, but try not doing this sort of wanky stuff. Static tableViews are not allowed to be used in UIViewController for a purpose. Apple had his reasons to prohibit it, so you better not search for work-arounds, otherwise  you will get a buggy app with unexpected behaviour. Do you really want that?

What I would suggest, as an idea for this situation:

Include a simple UITableView in your VC class, and just programmatically customise it in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
This way you get a stable situation with full control on it.